# How to reference firebase database in to another activity (used for updating db records)?

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Activity A where firebase db is created which allows adding data.

Now, I want to create another Activity B in android studio which will allow updating records to the firebase db created in Activity A.

How can I go about this?

Comment: You'd have to pass a reference to the DB object to Activity B. Alternatively you could create public methods in Activity A and call them from Activity B.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to pass a reference of DB object in Activity B please?

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference to the location in Activity B:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("location_where_you_saved");

Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put("name", newName);
ref.updateChildren(updates);
```

If in activity A, you created a node called `Books` and added attribute like `name` and `date`, then to update add the reference to child `Books` in Activity B, and update the records with new data as specified above.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields